# Edit query with join union tables - unwanted column in result

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to edit sql query to display in result every column except stuffId. Column stuffId is only for join purpose.

```
select
    *
from
    Stuff
    join
    (
        select
            stuffId
            , salary
            , hireDate
            , laptop
            , car
        from
            Employee
        union
        select
            stuffId
            , ROUND(Manager.salary + (Manager.salary * cast(bonus as float) / 100), 2) as salary
            , hireDate
            , laptop
            , car
    from
        Manager
    ) people
        on Stuff.id = people.stuffId
order by
    Stuff.id
```

Answer (score 1):

List the columns that you want in the `select`:

```
select stuff.col1, stuff.col2, . . ., 
       people.salary, people.hireDate, people.laptop, people.car
. . .
```

If you only want `stuffId` to appear once, then one method is:

```
select stuff.*, people.salary, people.hireDate, people.laptop, people.car
```

Another method would be to use `using` instead of `on`.

Comment: Works perfect. I forgot some basics but working on that now. Is there any good course for quick learn SQL query with excercises ? Im looking for one for C# too.

Answer (score 1):

Your very first line of code is requesting '*' (all the columns). You can specify columns that you want to view as an output. I modified your query, have to remove 'ORDER BY Stuff.id' since you dont want 'id' in your output.

```
select
    p.salary
    , p.hireDate
    , p.laptop
    , p.car
from
    Stuff s
    join
    (
        select
            stuffId
            , salary
            , hireDate
            , laptop
            , car
        from
            Employee
        union
        select
            stuffId
            , ROUND(Manager.salary + (Manager.salary * cast(bonus as float) / 100), 2) as salary
            , hireDate
            , laptop
            , car
    from
        Manager
    ) people p
        on s.id = p.stuffId
```

And you can select column from table Stuff to your liking.